# Is it possible to make right click act identically to left click, and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, mouse, mouseevent

The question is pretty well represented in the title, but is it possible to do this within Javascript or is this more of an OS feature?

To be clear, I want to simulate the firing of a left mouse click, not just a random mouse click indexed as 0, 1, 2, because I want the functionality of left click. I also need access to mousedown and mouseup and not just a click as a whole action.

The difference is I want to actually fire a left mousedown and left mouse up, and not just detect it.

Comment: This is somewhat possible.

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is right click a Javascript event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and get back to you guys.

Comment: DUPLICATE OF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988484/how-can-i-make-a-right-click-behave-as-a-left-click-for-the-purpose-of-selecting